# Looping through rows and multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in Python that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1.1.2023 | 32 | 21 |
| 12345 | 1.1.2023 | 54 | 43 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 58 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 85 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 34 |
| 12345 | 4.6.2017 | 54 | 22 |
| 12345 | 4.6.2017 | 33 | 33 |

I want to make a new column called "indicator", which would have binary values - 1 or 0: 1 if the same person has the same values of "Value 1" (or "Value 2") on the same date. So, for example, person 13459 would have value 1 since "Value_1" is 19 on 2.10.2020.
It should look like this:

| ID | Date | Value 1 | Value 2 | Indicator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1.1.2023 | 32 | 21 | 0 |
| 12345 | 1.1.2023 | 54 | 43 | 0 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 58. | 1 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 85 | 1 |
| 13459 | 2.10.2020 | 19 | 34 | 1 |
| 12345 | 4.6.2017 | 54 | 22 | 1 |
| 12345 | 4.6.2017 | 33 | 33 | 1 |

The thing is that the same person filled out a questionnaire multiple times, i.e. on multiple dates. I want to see which person has the same answer on the same date of the year.

I am working with pandas.
Thanks!

Comment: check your last `Value 2` : it differs between the input and output: `31` --> `22`. Correct your output

Answer (score 2):

Group by `ID, Date` and check if `Value 1` or `Value 2` has same values in each group:

```
g = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date'])
df['indicator'] = (g['Value 1'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1)
                   | g['Value 2'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1)).astype(int)
```

---

```
      ID        Date  Value 1  Value 2  indicator
0  12345   1.1.2023        32       21          0
1  12345   1.1.2023        54       43          0
2  13459  2.10.2020        19       58          1
3  13459  2.10.2020        19       85          1
4  13459  2.10.2020        19       34          1
5  12345   4.6.2017        54       22          0
6  12345   4.6.2017        33       31          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `melt` and `merge` which will allow you to run this over multiple columns.

```
s = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID','Date'])

s['indicator'] = (
       s.groupby(['ID','Date','value'])['value']\
            .transform('size') > 1).astype(int)
       )

df_out = pd.merge(df,s.drop_duplicates(
          subset=['ID','Date']
           ).drop(['value','variable'],axis=1)
          ,on=['Date','ID'],how='left')
```

print(df_out)

```
      ID       Date  Value 1  Value 2  indicator
0  12345   1.1.2023       32       21          0
1  12345   1.1.2023       54       43          0
2  13459  2.10.2020       19       58          1
3  13459  2.10.2020       19       85          1
4  13459  2.10.2020       19       34          1
5  12345   4.6.2017       54       22          0
6  12345   4.6.2017       33       31          0
```